# How can I download a file from Alfresco Server using java?

Tags: java, alfresco

As I am totally new in alfresco I have manually uploaded a file in alfresco server and now i want to download this uploaded file using java code, can anybody suggest/help me in it on how to achieve this scenario??

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest talking a look at REST and Java APIs:

- https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/
- https://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/concepts/dev-services.html
- https://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/references/dev-services-content.html

Answer (score 2):

As @lista suggests, you can do this via the 5.2 APIs. You can also take a look at the [Apache Chemistry OpenCMIS](https://chemistry.apache.org/java/download.html) library. It is also able to download files from Alfresco and is compatible with new and older versions of Alfresco as well as repositories from other vendors.